# Weblogic 12.2.1.3 hangs for some time while starting on linux

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, startup, weblogic12c

Attaching thread dump when it is stuck. Below is thread dump. I think there is some issue with muxer threads of weblogic as I can only see those thread which are waiting/locked on some glassfish methods.

I have also tried below JAVA_OPTIONS suggested for random number generator .

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

Also check available entropy which did not go below 3000. Total is 4096

```html
"weblogic.time.TimeEventGenerator" #28 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb1d05db000 nid=0x59a8 in Object.wait() [0x00007fb22d87c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at weblogic.time.common.internal.TimeTable.snooze(TimeTable.java:286)
    - locked <0x00000005c001ef40> (a weblogic.time.common.internal.TimeTable)
    at weblogic.time.common.internal.TimeEventGenerator.run(TimeEventGenerator.java:121)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" #27 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb1d05c0000 nid=0x59a7 in Object.wait() [0x00007fb22d97c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005c0007a28> (a org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:240)
    - locked <0x00000005c0007a28> (a org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000005c1e1deb8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000005da205758> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:786)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)

"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" #26 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb1d05b9000 nid=0x59a6 runnable [0x00007fb22da7b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.findPredecessor(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:691)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.doGet(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:781)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.get(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1546)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos$Cache.getAnnotationsOfInterest(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:872)
    - locked <0x00000005dd08a630> (a weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos$Cache)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos$Cache.access$700(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:840)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.getAnnotatedClassesByTargetsAndSources(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:656)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.hasAnnotatedClasses(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:705)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.hasCDIEnablingAnnotations(CDIUtils.java:782)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.isVirtualJarCdiEnabled(CDIUtils.java:590)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.areAnyEmbeddedJarsCdiEnabled(CDIUtils.java:463)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.isWebModuleCDIEnabled(CDIUtils.java:409)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIUtils.isModuleCdiEnabled(CDIUtils.java:651)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIModuleExtensionFactory.create(CDIModuleExtensionFactory.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.createModuleExtensions(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:264)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.initDrivenObjectArray(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:107)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:166)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:41)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:193)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:363)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:232)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000005c1e1e9c8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000005da22d8d0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)

"Timer-1" #25 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb1d05b6800 nid=0x59a5 in Object.wait() [0x00007fb22db7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000005c000fe90> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Timer-0" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25e2fc000 nid=0x598c in Object.wait() [0x00007fb22f9f5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005c00173c8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
    - locked <0x00000005c00173c8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Service Thread" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25df34000 nid=0x5983 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25df28800 nid=0x5982 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25df26000 nid=0x5981 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25df24000 nid=0x5980 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25df22800 nid=0x597f waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25deea800 nid=0x597d runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25c1d6800 nid=0x596d in Object.wait() [0x00007fb23dde4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    - locked <0x00000005c0017e30> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25c1d3800 nid=0x596c in Object.wait() [0x00007fb23dee5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000005c0017fe8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)
```

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb25c00c000 nid=0x5956 in Object.wait() [0x00007fb26586f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005c0017ff8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpAllTheWay.waitForResult(CurrentTaskFuture.java:518)
    - locked <0x00000005c0017ff8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture.get(CurrentTaskFuture.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture.get(CurrentTaskFuture.java:310)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFutureWrapper.get(CurrentTaskFutureWrapper.java:76)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:636)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:582)
    at weblogic.Server.embeddedMain(Server.java:95)
    at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:138)
```

Please let me know if I need to add more details.

Comment: Take several thread dumps during start up to detect long running thread(s)

Comment: what applications are deployed there? It seems it is trying to discover CDI beans, which probably could be disabled for particular application.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the JAVA OPTS parameter “-Ddisable-implicit-bean-discovery=true” start-up came down to around 5mins